# Real Projective Space $\mathbb{P}^2$ equivalence relation

Tags: general-topology

> **Definition.** The *real projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ of dimension $n$* is the set of $1$-dimensional linear subspaces (lines through the origin) in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

The projecive space can also be viewed as a quotient space. Define a relation $$x \sim y :\Leftrightarrow \exists\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^\times \text{ s.t. } x = \lambda y$$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$. Now in the topology book by John Lee, he mentions, that there is an obvious identification between $\mathbb{P}^n$ and the set of equivalence classes. What is this obvious identification? See, my problem is, that the lines in $\mathbb{P}^n$ go through the origin whereas in the quotient I do not really see why $0$ is in the equivalence classes.

Comment: Every _nonzero_ vector in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ determines a unique line through the origin. Two such vectors $x,y$ determine the same line if and only if $x\sim y$.